# What is the Best way to use angular with SharePoint

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, rest, jsom, angularjs

I'm trying to find the Best way to Build a SharePoint site(not an app) with Angular. I've multiple Content Editor webparts where I use the REST/JSOM to load content(Ex: Image Slider, List of Calendar upcooming events, some angular forms etc..).The question is how to efficiently create webparts so that I can just add the webpart where ever I want in my site. Right now I'm using following method.

1. create an app js and refer it JS in masterpage.
2. create a root
   element in each layout file (or in masterpage main
   contentplaceholder)
3. create a JS where I all the controllers
   resides(controllers.js-created by gulp, bundling) and refer in
   masterpage.
4. Each CEWP have an element with  ng-controller
   attribute.  in VS, create folder for each webpart(we call it
   feature), create a html,service and controller.
5. bundle all
   controller and services into a single JS file and refer them in
   masterpage.

   Is this the correct way to use angular with SharePoint? Please Guide if anyone have a better approach.

Thanks.

Comment: You can refer below link , It has very modular approach
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1002526/SharePoint-and-Angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sekhar, Here is my 2 paisa's (cents :) ) worth -

1. Build a global service for all crud functions - ideally a `factory`
2. Designate a landing page, (that would be the home/default page of your site). In this, add a cewp with reference to your spa html.
3. The SPA html (lets call it `app.html`) will have all your references of js and css.
4. Your webparts can either be a multiple components of a single view, or multiple subviews (ideally a mix of both)
5. Add further views and controllers - (in their own specific directory) as you need.

Make sure you follow [Angular Style Guide - John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) . Its comphrensive guide to angularJs best practices.

If you want to make a view with webparts intuitive, consider looking into

[Masonary JS](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

[Bootstrap Material Design](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/)